# VBA - If cell is empty, return empty cell for specific range

Tags: vba, excel

I have this function in my code which gets values from a particular range in multiple files *(a range from the last value in a column up to a designated header)* and prints them to one worksheet, my masterfile. It does this for two columns.

**My problem** is that sometimes I will have 1 value in one column and 8 in another. They should always be equal to each other in length so I would need the first column to print the 1 value cell followed by 7 blank cells.

I think the best way to go about it would be to grab the very first column in an opened file and have both of those columns print to the length of that one since it will always be the correct length. Any idea how to go about setting this up? I have been playing with it but cannot get it to work.

I thought I could set the value of the "TOOL NUM" column to n, and have everything print to length n (denoted as section (3) and (4) of my code). I just do not know how to set the latter up.

**Here is the area of code I am playing with, which goes right before section (3)**

```
   If Not Range("A1:A24").Find(What:="TOOL NUM", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
        Set n = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp)
```

In this line, in my masterfile that everything is printed to, I have it print down to the length of whatever column "C" is so I was hoping this would be a good basis to go off of for printing down to the length of whatever column 1 in the open file would be. Hope that is helpful.

```
StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = TDS
```

**FULL CODE:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Const ROW_HEADER As Long = 10

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim f As String
    Dim StartSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer
    Dim Height As Integer
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Dim hc As Range, hc1 As Range, hc2 As Range, hc3 As Range, hc4 As Range, d As Range
    Dim TDS As Range

    Set StartSht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    'turn screen updating off - makes program faster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'location of the folder in which the desired TDS files are
    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

    'find the headers on the sheet
    Set hc1 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("B1"), "HOLDER")
    Set hc2 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("C1"), "CUTTING TOOL")
    Set hc4 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("A1"), "TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 2


    'loop through directory file and print names
'(1)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" Or LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then
'(2)
            'Open folder and file name, do not update links
            Set WB = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name, UpdateLinks:=0)
            Set ws = WB.ActiveSheet




If Not Range("A1:A24").Find(What:="TOOL NUM", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
'(3)
                'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet
                Set hc = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "CUTTING TOOL")
                If Not hc Is Nothing Then
                    Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                    'add the values to the master list, column 3
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    Else
                        StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = ""
                    End If
                Else
                    StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "NO 'CUTTING TOOL' PRESENT!"
                End If
'(4)
                'find HOLDER on the source sheet
                Set hc3 = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "HOLDER")
                If Not hc3 Is Nothing Then
                    Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
                    'If InStr(ROW_HEADER, "HOLDER") <> "" Then
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        'add the values to the master list, column 2
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    Else
                        StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = ""
                    End If
                Else
                    StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "NO 'CUTTING TOOL' PRESENT!"
                End If
End If
'(5)
            With WB
                    'print the file name to Column 4
                    StartSht.Cells(i, 4) = objFile.Name

                    With ws
                    'Print TDS name by searching for header
                        If Not Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                            Set TDS = Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(, 1)
                            StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = TDS
                        Else
                            StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = "NO TDS VALUE!"
                        End If
                        i = GetLastRowInSheet(StartSht) + 1
                    End With
'(6)
                'close, do not save any changes to the opened files
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
'(7)
    'move to next file
    Next objFile
    'turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1 'brings the viewer to the top of the masterfile
End Sub

'(8)
'get all unique column values starting at cell c
Function GetValues(ch As Range, Optional vSplit As Variant) As Object
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim v
    Dim spl As Variant

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    For Each c In ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 And Not dict.exists(v) Then

            'exclude any info after ";"
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
            spl = Split(v, ";")
            v = spl(0)
            End If

            'exclude any info after ","
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
            spl = Split(v, ",")
            v = spl(0)
            End If

            dict.Add c.Address, v
        End If

        If Len(v) = 0 Then
            v = ""
        End If

'        If Len(v) = "" Then
'            v = ""
'        End If

    Next c
    Set GetValues = dict
End Function

'(9)
'find a header on a row: returns Nothing if not found
Function HeaderCell(rng As Range, sHeader As String) As Range
    Dim rv As Range, c As Range
    For Each c In rng.Parent.Range(rng, rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        'copy cell value if it contains some string "holder" or "cutting tool"
        If InStr(c.Value, sHeader) <> 0 Then
            Set rv = c
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    Set HeaderCell = rv
End Function

'(10)
Function GetLastRowInColumn(theWorksheet As Worksheet, col As String)
    With theWorksheet
        GetLastRowInColumn = .Range(col & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

'(11)
Function GetLastRowInSheet(theWorksheet As Worksheet)
Dim ret
    With theWorksheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            ret = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          LookAt:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            ret = 1
        End If
    End With
    GetLastRowInSheet = ret
End Function
```

**EDIT: Picture upload to clarify question in comments**
This image is what the opened files look like and I am grabbing from 2 columns "HOLDER" and "CUTTING TOOL" which here are labeled number and cutting tool
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the last row in the worksheet used range. Change

```
Function GetLastRowInColumn(theWorksheet As Worksheet, col As String)
    With theWorksheet
        GetLastRowInColumn = .Range(col & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

To

```
Function GetLastRowInSheet(theWorksheet As Worksheet)
    GetLastRowInColumn = theWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
End Function
```

I assume that your worksheets only contain necessary data and do not have a bunch of additional cells outside the desired range. For example, if everything is within `A1:C10`, and you have values below row 10, this will extend all the way to the bottom of the used range.

Edit: You'll also have to make sure you update references to the function. You could also probably move the single line of code to where it is being called and save yourself a few more lines.

Comment: I have a function below it called `GetLastRowInSheet` so I changed the name to just `GetLastRow`. When I try compiling it says that `GetLastRowInColumn` argument not optional since it is a function so(with the little knowledge I have of VBA so correct me if I'm wrong please) that would be because it does not know what that is since it is not in the function @pyriccrash

Comment: Also I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the range but in the files I am opening and grabbing data from, there is a lot of information but I am just grabbing from 2 specific columns. But yet there is more information all in that sheet if that's what you mean. I have uploaded a picture of what the opened files look like if that helps @pyriccrash

Comment: Looking through all your code, I see the `GetLastRowInSheet` function, the issue you're getting now, I suspect, is a result of changing the signature of the function. If you edited it as I proposed before, you may be trying to supply two arguments when it only expects one. The used range is basically if you had a box that contained every cell with a value or formatting applied, the extents of that box is the range. In looking through your code a bit more deeply, are you only running into the issue where you have a valid TDS?

Comment: I tried commenting out the other GetLastRowInSheet function to try your idea out and I still was given the same error back. As a summary of the code if that helps, my code opens the files, gets the information from the HOLDER and CUTTING TOOL columns, gets the information of the TDS number, and prints those into my masterfile along with the file name. the TDS number is printed down to the last value copied over from the CUTTING TOOL column so I guess I could go off of that column to print the HOLDER cells if that was easier. I am running into the issue when thre are empty cells in HOLDER

Comment: (cont.) but not empty cells in CUTTING TOOLS. The example I gave in my question that starts with **my problem** is one example of that. I hope that helps to clarify. @pyriccrash

Comment: I do not see a column header "HOLDER" in the image above, am I missing something, or is that a different worksheet?

Comment: Sorry that image is just a prototype, as I mentioned in the comment before it, HOLDER is equal to the column that says number to the left of cutting tool @pyriccrash